# Error en tkinter con Toplevel cuando cierro la ventana principal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Al instanciar una clase, entra dentro de un función que se me abre una ventana (toplevel) que el usuario debe elegir una cierta opción para que el programa pueda seguir ejecutándose, para ello en el código agregué la sentencia `wait_window()`.

Sucede que estoy ahí sin cerrar esa ventana (esperando), pero cuando le doy cerrar a la ventana principal con la X de la ventana de windows, me aparece un error en la terminal luego de haber cerrado diciendo:

> _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "toplevel" command: application has been destroyed

.
Lo que vendría luego de cerrar la ventana hija que pausaba el programa serían algunas sentencias mas y después crear otra ventana (Toplevel) que continuaría con la ejecución del programa, ahí en esa sentencia es cuando me tira error, lo curioso es que aparece luego de cerrar todo, como que continúa la ejecución del programa. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de esto y me pudiera dar una mano le agradezco.

Este es mi código:

**main.py:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from App import App

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('programa prueba')
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

**App.py:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Win import Win


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.pack(padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10))
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        open_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Button(
            open_frame,
            text="Boton",
            command=self.callback_button).pack()
        open_frame.pack()

    def callback_button(self):

        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.new_window = Win(top_level,self)
        self.new_window.pack()
        self.new_window.wait_window()

        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
```

**Win.py:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Win(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent,calc):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10))
```

Comment: Hola Miqueas, ¿Podrías agregar un [mcve] para poder reproducir el problema y ver más claramente que estás haciendo?

Comment: Hola, escribí un pequeño código de manera sencilla abajo.

Comment: Miqueas no debes usar las respuestas para agregar código, este apartado es solo para responder (valga la redundancia) a la pregunta. En su lugar usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159778/error-en-tkinter-cuando-cierro-la-ventana-principal?noredirect=1#comment301148_159778) que hay debajo de la pregunta y agrega en ella todo lo que quieras. La he editado por ti en esta ocasión, considera eliminar la "respuesta".

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, creo que estás malentendiendo el uso de `wait_window()`, esto en ningún momento te permite cerrar la ventana principal, instancia que además tiene el mainloop de la app. ¿Por qué quieres cerrar la ventana principal antes que las ventanas hijas? Si quieres poder cerrar la primera ventana y mantener la segunda que abres con Toplevel por ejemplo, no debes usar esta lógica, sino ocultar desde un principio la ventana principal y mostrar una TopLevel de inicio por ejemplo. Si me aclaras esto creo una respuesta explicándolo todo.

Comment: Yo cuando cierro la ventana principal, lo que deseo es que todas se cierren. Yo utilizo el wait_window porque necesito que el usuario en esa ventana elija cierta opción, que le va a permitir al programa seguir ejecutándose de manera correcta, eso se producirá en la siguiente ventana (que es el segundo toplevel que aparece con la ventana Win), pero yo no quiero que todo siga y cierro la principal y ahí es cuando aparece esa nota de error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a empezar explicando que hace el método `wait_window()`, simplemente este método no retorna hasta que la ventana/widget sobre la que se aplica no es destruido. Podía ser más legible llamarlo `self.wait_window(self.new_window)`.

Pero no tendría ninguna gracia que la llamada fuera bloqueante ya que bloquearía el *mainloop* y toda la app dejaría de responder por consiguiente. Por lo tanto lo que hace en realidad es crear un *eventloop* local que corre paralelamente al *mainloop* por lo que el código a ejecutar a partir de la llamada no será ejecutado hasta que `wait_window()` retorne pero sin bloquear el *mainloop* mientras tanto.

¿Qué ocurre en tu caso?

- Al pulsar el botón el método `callback_button()` es ejecutado, se crea la primera *TopLevel* y se llega a `self.new_window.wait_window()`, en ese punto la ejecución del método se bloquea y no continúa hasta que `self.new_window` sea destruida que es cuando `wait_window()` va a retornar.
- Si cierras la ventana `self.new_window`, el método `wait_window()` retorna y se ejecuta la siguiente línea del código `top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)`, todo bien.
- En cambio, si con `self.new_window` abierta cierras la ventana principal obtienes el error mencionado. Lo que ocurre es que la destrucción de la ventana principal ocasiona la destrucción de todas sus ventanas hijas, en ese momento `wait_window()`  retorna e intenta terminar la ejecución del método `callback_button()`, el problema es que al llegar a `top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)` la ventana principal ha sido destruida al igual que su `mainloop` y no podemos crear una ventana hija sin ella como es lógico. La clave está en entender que la destrucción de la ventana no implica que la llamada al método `callback_button()` no quede aún pendiente de ser completada.

Es un poco contradictorio que la ventana principal pueda ser cerrada cuando en teoría explícitamente le estamos diciendo que espere a que la hija termine. Si queremos permitir este comportamiento y evitar que la excepción se muestre podrías simplemente capturarla:

```
def callback_button(self):

    top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
    self.new_window = Win(top_level, self)
    self.new_window.pack()
    self.new_window.wait_window()

    try:
        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
    except tk.TclError:
        pass
```

Claro que la excepción se sigue produciendo y podemos considerarla una solución `fea`. Con algo más de trabajo podemos evitar que se produzca la excepción directamente:

- Definimos un atributo (booleano) que indique si la app está o no en funcionamiento en la ventana principal.
- Capturamos y manejamos por nosotros mismo el evento de cierre de la ventana principal, cuando esto ocurra el atributo anterior es pasado a `False`.
- Esto permite condicionar el resto del código del método `callback_button` a si la app sigue o no en funcionamiento.

Podría quedar así:

```
class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.pack(padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10))
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.create_widgets()
        self._is_runnig = True


    def create_widgets(self):
        open_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Button(
            open_frame,
            text="Boton",
            command=self.callback_button).pack()
        open_frame.pack()
        self.new_window = None


    def callback_button(self):
        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.new_window = Win(top_level, self)
        self.new_window.pack()
        self.new_window.wait_window()

        if not self._is_runnig:
            return

        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)


    def on_closing(self):
        self._is_runnig = False
        self.root.destroy()
```

Comment: Ahora si entiendo lo que ocurre, funciona perfecto!.
Sólo me queda una pequeña duda menor, y es el hecho de cuando se destruye la ventana, el objeto App sigue existiendo por lo que se puede ejecutar sin problemas la sentencia que evalúa self.is_runnig, solamente no se ve más la ventana.
De no ser aclarada mi duda igual te agradezco grandemente la respuesta brindada. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: @MiqueasRodríguez efectivamente, se destruye la app pero la clase Python no va a ser destruida por el GC mientras su contador de referencias no esté a 0, así mismo el código pendiente por ejecutar va a se ejecutado.

Comment: Es algo complejo, ten en cuanta que tkinter es una capa orientada a objetos sobre [Tcl/Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/). Cuando instanciamos `tk.Tk`  se inicia un intérprete Tcl y tkinter se encarga de traducir el código Python a tcl/tk y se lo pasa al intérprete.  Cuando destruimos la ventana principal el intérprete TCL termina , otra cosa son los objetos Python. Es como si sigues hablando (clase Python) al teléfono cuando tu interlocutor (intérprete Tcl) ha colgado, por eso la excepción.

Comment: Se me aclaró mucho más el panorama ahora, gracias por la explicación!